# Parse Server [Cloud Code]: Handle concurrent requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

Let's say I have some Cloud Code on Parse Server:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("UserProfiles", function(request, response) {
    const query = new Parse.Query("UserProfiles");
    query.equalTo("user", request.user);
    query.count({
        success: function(count) {
            if(count == 0)
                response.success();
            else 
                response.error("only one profile is allowed");  
            },
        error: function(error) {
                response.error(error.message);
            }
    });
});
```

It works fine unless concurrency happen. If two or more requests at the same time execute creation of new classes then this code wouldn't check that profile under pointer field user already exist.

My question is how properly handle concurrent requests in beforeSave trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by ensuring your UserProfile collection has an index by user in your database. You'll have to figure out how to do this yourself based on your database provider. This will speed up your queries.

Otherwise, you don't have a lot of options here. I'd say the best bet is to put the code that creates the UserProfile object inside the beforeSave trigger for Parse.User, inside a block that checks for .isNew(), so it only gets created when a new user is created. Any other solution I can think of would have similar concurrency issues.

Comment: I think add unique index in the collection of mongodb is the solution. But why parse server doesn't support it from the box? Not obvious to manage your db indexes manually

Comment: Parse.com used to and if you migrated your app from there, it automatically migrated all of the indexes as well. However, the feature wasn't super robust and could often lead to slow downs if you ended up with too many indexes. Indexes improve search time but decrease write time, since each write to a Collection requires updating all of the indexes.  The feature was removed more or less because it was part of the paid package of hosting on Parse.com - they managed the database. Parse-Server provides the infrastructure for your server, and you manage your own database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `BeforeSave()` you can set the the `UserProfiles` pointer to the user object before saving like so:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, respone){
    // only apply to new users
      if(request.object.isNew()){
        var UserProfile = new Parse.Object.extend("UserProfiles");
        var userProfile = new UserProfile();
        return userProfile.save().then(function(savedUserProfile){
          request.object.set("key", savedUserProfile);
          return request.object.save();
        });
      }
});
```

you can achive that by either `Cloud jobs`, `beforeSave` or `afterSave` callbacks